# Executing local script on remote server with local input

Tags: bash, ssh, remote

I have a `python` script and input data that the python script takes.

I want to execute the python script on remote server *without copying python script and data to the remote server*.

I tried the script:

```
ssh dong@xxx.27.35.xxx "cd /home/dong/fold python -u -" <  script.py arg1
```

It execute the script but the `arg1` (which is input data) python script doesn't take from local machine but when the input data present in remote server it works.

I hope experts may show some way to overcoming this problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135993/discussion-on-question-by-stuar-rty-executing-local-script-on-remote-server-with).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, but there's also a caveat. Read the whole answer before you attempt anything.

Create a new named pipe (fifo) on the server:

```
ssh dong@xxx.27.35.xxx 'cd /home/dong/fold && mkfifo myfifo'
```

The command should return almost immediately, make sure it succeeded. Now let your remotely running script treat the named pipe as a file to work with. This command should block, this is expected, let it run:

```
ssh dong@xxx.27.35.xxx 'cd /home/dong/fold && python -u - myfifo' < script.py
```

While the above command waits, feed the named pipe from your local computer (obviously you need another local console for this):

```
ssh dong@xxx.27.35.xxx 'cd /home/dong/fold && cat > myfifo' < arg1
```

This should unblock the previous command, the two commands should now transfer data.

Notes and caveats:

- `cd` does not consume its stdin, so all the content of local `script.py` will go to the remote `python` and all the content of local `arg1` will go to the remote `cat`. If you're not sure and you absolutely want to be on the safe side, you can always redirect the stdin of `cd` away from important data (`</dev/null cd …`). An overkill in case of `cd`, but if you insert yet another tool for any reason and the tool may read its stdin, then such redirection may solve the problem.
- Reading from the named pipe blocks until there's a writing process; writing to the named pipe blocks until there's a reading process. This means `cat` and `python` may start in any order, you don't need to synchronize them additionally. If you want to implement the solution in a (local) shell script or do everything in a single local console then it makes sense to run `ssh … cat …` first asynchronously (i.e. in the background). The important thing is to create the named pipe before anything on the server tries to use it; that's why I placed `mkfifo myfifo` inside a separate `ssh` command.
- There's a mechanism of connection sharing, it allows you to run many `ssh`s over a single connection to the server. See `man 1 ssh`, [`-M`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#M) and `-S` options. This is especially handy when authenticating with a password, wanting to put some `ssh`(s) in the background and not being able to use `ssh -f` for this (e.g. because it implies `-n` and you don't want `-n`). You start with `ssh -fNMS …` that handles the authentication and goes to the background, then you invoke as many `ssh -S …` as you want (possibly in the background), eventually you run `ssh -O exit -S …` to terminate the master connection. I won't elaborate.
- When `myfifo` is no longer needed, you can remove it like any other file (`rm myfifo` in the right directory on the server).
- Finally **the main caveat**.

  The local `script.py` is transferred via stdin of one local `ssh` and the data is available as a non-seekable stream on the stdin of the remotely running `python`. This should not be a problem, it's already this way in your original code and AFAIK `python` can handle this.

  Similarly the local `arg1` is transferred via stdin of another local `ssh` and this data is available as a non-seekable stream the remotely running `python` may read from `myfifo`. **This will work only if the python script reads sequentially from the file and does not expect the file to be seekable**. What you read from a pipe is not seekable, thus what your script reads from the pipe is not seekable. If the script tries to seek then it will fail. If the script tries to write to `myfifo` then it will fail or misbehave (the script is absolutely not able to modify the local `arg` this way). **The ability or inability of your script to do the desired job by working with `myfifo` totally depends on the details of the script** which are undisclosed.

  If the python script needs the file to be seekable then you must either provide a copy of the local `arg` as a regular file on the server (you explicitly stated you don't want this, still a simple copy is the most *straightforward* solution) or mount the local `arg` on the server, so it appears as a *regular file* there. The latter method is a non-trivial task. Without help from the admin of the server, you are limited to [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)-based solutions like `sshfs` or `curlftpfs` (*if* FUSE is enabled at all). And you need to turn your local computer into a server of the chosen protocol; and you need to make sure the other computer can reach your local computer. I won't elaborate.

Comment: second command gets block and doesnot get unblock

Comment: @stuarrty Does the third command exit? Again: the ability or inability of your script to do the desired job by working with `myfifo` totally depends on the details of the script which are undisclosed. I have tested my solution with the `cat`-mimicking script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411471/10765659) (the one described as "Or to allow arbitrary large lines"). It works. This particular script is designed to be able to work with a pipe and therefore it works with `myfifo`. I know nothing about your script.

Comment: script is little confidential but i can share with you if you can provide the mail id or some link, third command executed successfully but no output

Comment: @stuarrty This site does not work like that. You can edit the question and post the script there (with proper formatting) for all to see. Please note I'm not a programmer, I don't know Python at all, I probably won't be able to analyze it. Besides, in general we are not for analyzing code (especially if it's more than a few lines). If the third command exited then either you messed something up and it didn't write to the fifo (check the paths, maybe you created a regular file elsewhere on the server), or your script read from the fifo once and then expected more (reopened it to read again?).

Comment: ok ...thanks not sucessful finally